# 'safe_queue.h' file not found on my project

Tags: android, c++

## Background

I try to build an android app with ffmpeg support to play local video file. But I confused on a stranger problem.

## Problem

I write the code:

```
#include "safe_queue.h"
```

to include SafeQueue, but IDE show me that **'safe_queue.h' file not found.**

I am a newer on C/C++ programming, I can not know what wrong with this, what happen, and how can I fix it. further more, If I encounter a similar problem in the future, how can I fix it.

Could somebody help me, or discussing about what wrong with my code. Thanks!

## **strong text**Code

My CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/ffmpeg/include)

add_library(
        avplayer
        SHARED
        avplayer/avplayer.cpp
        avplayer/PreparerCallback.cpp
        avplayer/AudioChannel.cpp
)

set(lib_src_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/ffmpeg/libs/${CMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI})

add_library(avcodec SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(avcodec PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
        ${lib_src_DIR}/libavcodec.so)

add_library(avdevice SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(avdevice PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
        ${lib_src_DIR}/libavdevice.so)

add_library(avfilter SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(avfilter PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
        ${lib_src_DIR}/libavfilter.so)

add_library(avformat SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(avformat PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
        ${lib_src_DIR}/libavformat.so)

add_library(avutil SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(avutil PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
        ${lib_src_DIR}/libavutil.so)

add_library(swresample SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(swresample PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
        ${lib_src_DIR}/libswresample.so)

add_library(swscale SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(swscale PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
        ${lib_src_DIR}/libswscale.so)

find_library(log_lib log)

target_link_libraries(
        avplayer
        avcodec
        avdevice
        avfilter
        avformat
        avutil
        swresample
        swscale
        android
        ${log_lib})
```

My code:
BaseChannel.h:

```
#ifndef VIDEOPLAYER_BASECHANNEL_H
#define VIDEOPLAYER_BASECHANNEL_H

extern "C" {
#include "../../ffmpeg/include/libavutil/rational.h"
#include "../../ffmpeg/include/libavcodec/avcodec.h"
}

#include "PreparerCallback.h"
#include "safe_queue.h" /// `safe_queue.h` file not found.

class BaseChannel {
public:

    int stream_index;
    AVCodecContext *context;
    PreparerCallback *preparerCallback;
    AVRational base_time;
    double audio_time;
    double video_time;

    
    /// No template named 'SafeQueue'
    SafeQueue<AVPacket *> packages; 

    
    /// No template named 'SafeQueue'
    SafeQueue<AVFrame *> frames; 

    BaseChannel(int stream_index, AVCodecContext *pContext, AVRational av_base_time,
                PreparerCallback *callback) {
        this->stream_index = stream_index;
        this->context = pContext;
        this->base_time = av_base_time;
        this->preparerCallback = callback;
    }

    virtual ~BaseChannel() {

    }
};
```

AudioChannel.h:

```
#ifndef VIDEOPLAYER_AUDIOCHANNEL_H
#define VIDEOPLAYER_AUDIOCHANNEL_H


#include "BaseChannel.h"

class AudioChannel : public BaseChannel {

};


#endif //VIDEOPLAYER_AUDIOCHANNEL_H
```

Comment: My understanding is that `safe_queue.h` is not part of C++ standard. You have to install/download it.

Comment: @Damien thanks for your advising, i try to install/download it...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Damien!
Finally I check my code and find that "safe_queue.h" is not C++ standard. I use std::queue instead.